# How should my createFragment method return my fragments?

Tags: java, android

What should the return value at the bottom be? By setting null I can make my app work. However, I would like to get rid of the warning in Android Studio without suppressing it.

Android Studio is obviously telling me "*'null' is returned by the method declared as @NonNull*".

Is there a better way to return my fragments?

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
    String className = mContext.getClass().getSimpleName();

    // Check which Activity is using the ViewHolder and return the appropriate Fragments.
    switch (className) {
        case "VancouverActivity":
            if (position == 0) {
                return new VancouverMainFragment();
            } else if (position == 1) {
                return new VancouverAttractionsFragment();
            } else if (position == 2) {
                return new VancouverCoffeeFragment();
            } else if (position == 3) {
                return new VancouverRestaurantFragment();
            } else {
                return new VancouverActivitiesFragment();
            }
        case "SaskatoonActivity":
            if (position == 0) {
                return new SaskatoonMainFragment();
            } else if (position == 1) {
                return new SaskatoonAttractionsFragment();
            } else if (position == 2) {
                return new SaskatoonCoffeeFragment();
            } else if (position == 3) {
                return new SaskatoonRestaurantFragment();
            } else {
                return new SaskatoonActivitiesFragment();
            }
        case "TorontoActivity":
            if (position == 0) {
                return new TorontoMainFragment();
            } else if (position == 1) {
                return new TorontoAttractionsFragment();
            } else if (position == 2) {
                return new TorontoCoffeeFragment();
            } else if (position == 3) {
                return new TorontoRestaurantFragment();
            } else {
                return new TorontoActivitiesFragment();
            }
        case "StJohnsActivity":
            if (position == 0) {
                return new StJohnsMainFragment();
            } else if (position == 1) {
                return new StJohnsAttractionsFragment();
            } else if (position == 2) {
                return new StJohnsCoffeeFragment();
            } else if (position == 3) {
                return new StJohnsRestaurantFragment();
            } else {
                return new StJohnsActivitiesFragment();
            }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You need to cover all the possible return cases so this is how it should be  . Just add a check for null where you are using this returned value and mark the Method @Nullable.

Comment: If you're sure you've covered all cases your method can end by throwing `IllegalArgumentException`.